# UILabel Number Situation

Tags: ios, xcode, uitextfield, uilabel, uistepper

Example I:

```
if (textField.text = @"0", @"1", @"2", @"3", @"4", @"5", @"6", @"7", @"8", @"9", @"10") { label.text = @"0"; }
if (textField.text = @"11", @"12", @"13", @"14", @"15", @"16") { label.text = @"10"; }
if (textField.text = @"17", @"18", @"19", @"20", @"21", @"22") { label.text = @"20"; }
if (textField.text = @"23", @"24", @"25", @"26", @"27", @"28") { label.text = @"30"; }
```

As you can see below,  I have a UIStepper that adds in a text field one by one, but here is what I want to do with the label: Once I get to eleven every six steps up the label will add 10 points (Example I).

But I'm pretty sure I've done a terrible job, Can someone help me?

Comment: Seems easier to convert the textfield value to an integer and then do numerical comparisons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
int value = [textfield.text intValue];
```

then do your value checking with integer numbers. You could use modulo or any other arithmetic then. To return it to a string do this:

```
label1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",value];
```

If your textfield contains integer values then textfield.text (an nsstring) can become an integer using the int value above. Afterwards, it's easy to check in which case the value is. The simplest is using ifs like this:

```
 if (value <=10) {
  label.text = @"0";
 } else {
   if ( value > 10 && value <=16 ) {
    label.text = @"10";
   } else { if ( value > 16 and value <= 22) {
      label.text = @"20";
     } 
   }
 }
```

and so on. As I said, it's the simplest if..else construct and comparison.

Comment: See my updated answer, in a few minutes. I had my internet down.

Comment: Remember, this is the simplest way (for people learning any language), you should improvise your own algorithm, once you get more acquainted.